# How to get only row without a specific value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

this is a huge problem i've to solve in sql but i don't know how. 
This is my dataset:

```
customer; publisher; qty
```

This is a data sample:

```
CustA;  PublX;  10
CustA;  PublZ;  20
CustA;  PublF;  30
CustB;  PublX;   8
CustC;  PublD;   9 
CustD;  PublX;   9
CustD;  MyPub;  18
CustE;  PublZ;   3
CustE;  MyPub;   8
```

I need to do a Query that get ONLY Customer without "MyPubl" as publisher. 
Obviously i can't do :

SELECT * from myTable where Publisher <>"MyPubl"

One solution can be that i create a subset table that aggregate customer in one row like this:

```
CustA; PublX PublZ PublF; 60
CustB; PublX; 8
etc...
```

Then with a INSTR i check if MyPub exists in second field ...
This solution my work.. so i ask you How can i do this in SQL (aggregate 'same' customers in one row) ?

Any others suggestion (maybe more elegant) ?

Thanks

Comment: *Why* can't you do `<>`/`!=`?

Comment: That would return CustE, which has MyPub in one row, and something else in another.

Comment: @ColmPrunty Aha! Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN` with a sub query:

```
SELECT
    customer,
    publisher,
    qty
FROM
    books
WHERE
    customer NOT IN (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT customer
        FROM
            books
        WHERE
            publisher = 'MyPub'
    )
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b42bb/3/0)

Which will output:

```
CUSTOMER | PUBLISHER | QTY
---------+-----------+-----
CustA    | PublZ     |  20
CustA    | PublF     |  30
CustB    | PublX     |   8
CustC    | PublD     |   9
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE customer NOT IN (SELECT customer FROM myTable WHERE Publisher = "MyPubl")
```

Or if you just want the customers

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Or old skool...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.customer 
           FROM my_table x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.customer = x.customer 
            AND y.publisher = 'MyPub' 
          WHERE y.customer IS NULL;
```